# Internal users can't see data when they loginto communities

Tags: community

We want to test the new community we built for our external users. when internal users other than administrators login to the community they can see their data. pages are displayed but no data.

They are using Salesforce license

Comment: do their profiles have access to the documents/records ?

Comment: What are OWD for the objects when viewed in the Community? I'd expect them to be different than from production org. Just because they have a Salesforce License, doesn't mean the security applied to the Community still won't apply. What kind of Community License do you have? How are records shared in the community? All these things come into play.

Comment: We have View All Data and View All permission on OWD. We have same license 'Salesforce' in both Sandbox and Production.

Comment: I think I was wrong, actually no one including administrators can see data when login to comminites through login page

Comment: have you added the members that should have access to the community? Administration>Members>select Profiles - and is your community Public?

Comment: Yes profile was added already and the our community is public.

Comment: and as an admin in the community builder, you do see records when searching in preview mode?

Comment: No even admin can't see any records